# IrfanView startup switches - Toggle caption, toolbar, status, etc

Tags: irfanview

I need to start [IrfanView](https://irfanview.com) and automatically toggle-off the caption, menu, statusbar and toolbar.

From within the app, you can press <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>C</kbd> (then M, S, T) to toggle these features manually. Is there a way to do this on startup, using start-up switches?

I attempted to register for the [IrfanView forum](https://irfanview-forum.de/) to ask this question there, but the registration system appears broken.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### I need to start IrfanView and hide the caption, menu, statusbar and toolbar.

Use the following command line option:

```
/hide=15
```

> **Example for `/hide`:**
>
> Values (can be combined (add values)):
>
> ```
> Toolbar 1
> Status bar 2
> Menu bar 4
> Caption 8
> ```
>
> Open 'c:\test.jpg', hide toolbar only.
>
> ```
> i_view32.exe c:\test.jpg /hide=1
> ```
>
> Open 'c:\test.jpg', hide toolbar and status bar.
>
> ```
> i_view32.exe c:\test.jpg /hide=3
> ```
>
> Open 'c:\test.jpg', hide caption and menu bar.
>
> ```
> i_view32.exe c:\test.jpg /hide=12
> ```
>
> Open 'c:\test.jpg', hide all.
>
> ```
> i_view32.exe c:\test.jpg /hide=15
> ```

Source [IrfanView Command Line Options - ETCwiki](http://www.etcwiki.org/wiki/IrfanView_Command_Line_Options)

Comment: Thanks! I am grateful for the examples, and particularly appreciate the reference/link to the ETCwiki page. Most helpful - check + 1